# Deleting the indices in Array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code for deleting the indices inside the array, but it seems not to work

```
import numpy as np
length=4
indices=np.arange(length)
for num in (indices):
        np.delete(indices, num)
        print("checking", indices, num)
```

What seems to be the issue? does `np.delete` not work on arrays?

Comment: You need to go through the documentation more clearly, `np.delete` is not equivalent to `.pop` and also you aren't deleting the numbers, but rather entire axis and not in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better not iterating a container while changing its length. Try working with indexed instead :

```
import numpy as np
length=4
indices=np.arange(length)
for i in reversed(range(len(indices))):
        indices = np.delete(indices, i)
        print("checking", indices, i)
```

If you're looking for deletion by element you could find the element index before using delete :

```
import numpy as np
length=4
elements=np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])
for i in elements:
        idx = np.where(elements == i)
        elements = np.delete(elements, idx)
        print("checking", elements, i)
```

Comment: this is closer to what  I want as in the end I get empty list.  But I really want to delete based on the indices of the actual array so reverse(range... won't work in my case.

Comment: is there any way to delete via element instead of index? so element 2 can be anywhere in the array and it will delete 2 if I give designation of 2

Answer (score 1):

Numpy array is immutable. So you cannot delete an item from it. However, you can construct a new array without the values you don't want, like this:

```
new_indices = np.delete(indices, [0,1,2])
```

In your code, you can try to get new array after deleting the element, by assigning it to a variable as below:

```
new_indices = np.delete(indices, num)
print(new_indices, indices) # prints [1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]
```

Now if you print new_indices it will not have the element at index num

Comment: thanks, but I want to make it completely empty, each iteration of the loop will only delete one particular num while other that was deleted in previous iteration will persist.

Comment: You are right. As @dspr mentioned it is not good to update the array while iterating as the original array is not getting updated

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html?highlight=delete#numpy.delete) returns a **copy** of given array, it doesn't modify existing one.